# MongoDB, parent with child IDs or child with singular parent ID?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, mongoose, database-schema

quick question...

In MongoDB is it better to have a parent record with an array of child IDs?  Or for every child to have a "parent" column with the parent ID?

Which is more efficient/cost effective memory wise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The children should have parent IDs so that the number of children can grow without bound.  Putting children IDs in the parent would cause the parent document to grow over time leading to document moves as the doc needs more space on disk and ultimately the 16MB limit on doc sizes.  Though if you get to that 16MB limit you probably have other issues...